# How to insert large files in gridfs with php

Tags: php, mongodb, gridfs

I'm coding a web application in php using mongodb and I would like to store very large files (1gb) with gridfs.

I've got 2 problems, first I get a timeout, and I can't find out how to set the cursor timeout of the MongoGridFS class.

```
  <?php
  //[...]
  $con = new Mongo();
  $db = $con->selectDB($conf['base']);
  $grid = $db->getGridFS();

  $file_id = $grid->storeFile($_POST['projectfile'], 
                  array('metadata' => array('type' => 'release', 
                  'version' => $query['files'][$time]['version'], 
                  'mime' => mime_content_type($_POST['projectfile']),
                  'filename' => file_name($projectname).'-'.file_name($query['files'][$time]['version']).'.'
                  .getvalue(pathinfo($_POST['projectfile']), 'extension'))), array( 'safe' => false ));
  //[...]
  ?>
```

And secondly I wonder if it were possible to execute the request in the background? When I store the file with this query, the execution is blocked and I get an error 500 due to the timeout

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoGridFSException' with
>   message 'Could not store file: cursor timed out (timeout: 30000, time
>   left: 0:0, status: 0)'

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be better to store your files in some directory, and put in database only location of that file? It will be rather quick.

Answer (score 0):

Gridfs queries, by default, are not "safe" however they are not a single query in the driver. This function must run multiple queries within the driver (one to store a `fs.files` row and one to split the `fs.chunks`). This means that the timeout is most likely occuring on a `find` needed to process further batches of information, it might even be related to the PHP tiemout rather than a MongoDB one.

The easiest way to use this in the background is to create a "job" via calling a cronjob or using a message queue to another service.

As for the timeout; unfortunately the gridfs functions (on your side) don't have direct access to the cursor being used (other than setting safe), you can set a timeout on the connection but I wouldn't think this is a wise idea.

However if your cursor is timing out it means (as I said) that a `find` query is probably taking too long in which case you might wanna monitor the MongoDB logs to find out what is timing out, this might just be a simple case of needing better indexes or a more performant setup.

As @Anton said, you can also consider housing large files outside of MongoDB, however, there is no requirement.

Comment: After looking log, mongo returns timeout after a serie of this: 
`getmore db.fs.chunks cid:4130855842018803829 ntoreturn:0 query: { query: { files_id: ObjId(509286b2fbd7cf6750000002) }, orderby: { files_id: 1, n: 1 } }  bytes:1048860 nreturned:4 104ms`

Comment: @Goldy Hmm it seems to be timing out when fetching all chunks. Can you check the indexes on your `fs.chunks` collection and add it to the question? Also check your firewall settings and that and make sure that the cursor isn't working overtime from having to resend data

Comment: @Goldy You might be getting problems with the default size of the fs chunk which is 256kb, which makes 40K rows in your chunks collection. If you were to up it to 16meg it might help by making only 64 rows.

Comment: I can only up to 4meg in my mongodb version, so this not possible... I will copy the files on disk.

Comment: @Goldy Yea do that, ah your using a very old MongoDB, I would strongly recommend upgrading, thsi query might actually work on the latest version fine.